# Ошибка при установке laravel на Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, composer, install

```
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (The "https://repo.packagist.org/p2/nunomaduro/termwind~dev.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Success
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/pint ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/pint[v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0].
    - laravel/pint[v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0] require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-xml --ignore-platform-req=ext-dom` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

Использую Xampp(8.1.6) на Ubuntu 20.04

До этой установки я делал:

1. Обновил PHP до 8 версии
2. 

```bash
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache

rm -rf /path/to/project/vendor

rm /path/to/project/composer.lock

composer --prefer-dist install
```

3 пункт не сработал(не нашел чего-то)

3. удалил прошлую версию laravel из папки проекта(не с сервера, они у меня отдельно расположенны)
4. запустил новую установку laravel
   и Вот резльтат

Comment: ```To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:``` в php.ini файле нужно раскомментировать строки с нужными расширениями расширениями. А в ```Problem``` указано, какие расширения нужны

Comment: А патом что делать

Comment: сохраняешь файл и запускаешь установку по новому

Comment: Там нету таких расширений

Comment: Install or enable PHP's xml extension.

Comment: получается нужно установить, а это тоже вопрос

Comment: @Linar46 А в чём вопрос? В том, как модули ставить? `apt install php8.1-xml`

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему, Vladimir Gonchar